# Adding a store to GeoServer: Restricting access to file system

Tags: geoserver

When adding a store to Geoserver I can restrict access to the underlying file system by modifying web.xml (ref: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/filebrowse.html). However, is it possible to restrict access for a given user in GeoServer to a specific directory on the underlying server?

I've looked into Geofence, but as far as I can tell all users added to GeoServer will still be able to browse to all of the GeoServer data when adding a store. Preferably I would like to specify access to a particular directory on the server for a given GeoServer user when they add a new store. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

I'm using GeoServer 2.16.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, at present at least (with GeoServer 2.16.x or 2.17.x). It could be implemented with some coding effort/sponshorship.